# Update field of a power-up from Trello API

Tags: trello, trello-powerup

I am using [Trello's REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/) to create cards in my board. I have enabled in my board some power ups, like [Star](https://trello.com/power-ups/5e40446acc3ae64e435cabc9/stars)

Is there a way to update Star's field from API as well?

Comment: I've enabled Stars power-up and found `{\"stars\":5,\"stars-category\":null}` in .json. I think we can handle those custom fields like usual.

Comment: I've searched [the API doc](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/) and I'm afraid that there's no API for 'update' `pluginData`. Only 'get' exists.